# Scraping links in df columns with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have a dataframe where one of the columns contains the links to webpages I want to scrape with rvest. I would like to download some links, store them in another column, and download some texts from them. I tried to do it using `lapply` but I get `Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "function"` at the second step. Maybe the problem could be that the first links are saved as a list. Do you know how I can solve it?

This is my MWE (in my full dataset I have around 5000 links, should I use `Sys.sleep` and how?)

```
library(rvest)

df <- structure(list(numeroAtto = c("2855", "2854", "327", "240", "82"
), testo = c("http://dati.camera.it/ocd/versioneTestoAtto.rdf/vta18_leg.18.pdl.camera.2855.18PDL0127540", 
             "http://dati.camera.it/ocd/versioneTestoAtto.rdf/vta18_leg.18.pdl.camera.327.18PDL0003550",
             "http://dati.camera.it/ocd/versioneTestoAtto.rdf/vta18_leg.18.pdl.camera.327.18PDL0003550", 
             "http://dati.camera.it/ocd/versioneTestoAtto.rdf/vta18_leg.18.pdl.camera.240.18PDL0007740", 
             "http://dati.camera.it/ocd/versioneTestoAtto.rdf/vta18_leg.18.pdl.camera.82.18PDL0001750"
)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

df$links_text <- lapply(df$testo, function(x) {
  page <- read_html(x)
  links <- html_nodes(page, '.value:nth-child(8) .fixed') %>%
    html_text(trim = T)
})

df$text <- lapply(df$links_text, function(x) {
  page1 <- read_html(x)
  links1 <- html_nodes(page, 'p') %>%
    html_text(trim = T)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do this in single `sapply` command and use `tryCatch` to handle errors.

```
library(rvest)

df$text  <- sapply(df$testo, function(x) {
  tryCatch({
    x %>%
      read_html() %>%
      html_nodes('.value:nth-child(8) .fixed') %>%
      html_text(trim = T) %>%
      read_html %>%
      html_nodes('p') %>%
      html_text(trim = T) %>%
      toString()
  }, error = function(e) NA)
})
```

Comment: Than you very much, it works! however, when I use it for my full dataset, I get `Error: Document is empty`. Maybe some links are not working? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Yes, you may use `tryCatch`, see the updated answer @Edoardo

Answer (score 2):

You want `links1 <- html_nodes(page, 'p')` to refer to `page1`, not `page`.

[Otherwise (as there is no object `page` in the function environment, it is trying to apply html_nodes to the utils function `page`]

In terms of `Sys_sleep`, it is fairly optional. Check in the page html and see whether there is anything in the code or user agreement prohibiting scraping. If so, then scraping more kindly to the server might improve your chances of not getting blocked!

You can just include `Sys.sleep(n)` in your function where you create `df$text`. n is up to you, I've had luck with 1-3 seconds, but it does become pretty slow/long!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I just realised that the first `lapply` returns a list. As a result, after the second `lapply` I end up with a text that merges the texts contained in all the webpages. Do you have any suggestion?